# ManyToMany NOT NULL check constraint when using Named query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, hsqldb

I have an Entity (`Layer`) that maps a list of other Entities (`Member`). This List may have no entries / be `null`. Yet, when I query for the Entity I get a `NOT NULL check constraint` error from the database.
It seems to be connected to the `NamedQueries` as I can read the Entity from DB if I query by `id`.

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="getChildLayers",-
                query = "SELECT la
                         FROM Layer la
                         WHERE la.parent = :parent AND la.deletedDate IS NULL")})
public class Layer extends CommonModel {
    /*... other field */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Layer.class, optional = true)
    private Layer parent;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = MyUser.class)
    private List<MyUser> members;
    public List<MyUser> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }
    public void setMembers(List<MyUser> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }
    /*... other getters and setters */
}
```

I get this error: `integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10298 table: LAYER_MYUSER column: MEMBERS_ID`

I am able to create the entry, though.

When I run my tests then all tests fail that read the Entity (but creation works). If I add the following line in the creation method:

```
  layer.setMembers(new ArrayList<MyUser>());
```

then the methods that test the alternation of the members work (meaning, I can create a `Layer` and alter its `members` by adding and removing elements from the list).

It seems to me that reading the Entity from Database fails whenever there are no `Member` to the `Layer`.

I did try adding `@JoinColumn(nullable=true)` to the field, but it changed nothing.

I import `javax.persistence` classes.

Example as to how I access the variable (in `LayerService`)

```
// this method works as expected
public Layer getById(Long id) {
    Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return (Layer)s.get(Layer.class, id);
}

// this does not.
public List<Layer> getChildren(Layer layer) {
    Query childrenQuery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("getChildLayers");
    childrenQuery.setParameter("parent", layer);

    return (List<Layer>) childrenQuery.list();
}
```

---

Code changed after Jason Cs answer:

`Layer`

```
...
private final List<OCWUser> members = new ArrayList<>();
...
public void setMembers(List<OCWUser> members) {
    this.members.clear();
    this.members.addAll(members);
}
```

Problem still exists.

Comment: Do you create table's manually?

Comment: @frostjogla No, the tables are created automatically.

Comment: Hibernate create 'LAYER_MYUSER' table with columns 'MEMBERS_ID BIGINT NOT NULL' and 'MYUSER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL' http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-join-m2m. Try remove manually 'not null' constraint from columns.

Comment: @frostjogla I'd rather not have to modify the database manually. There has to be a different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be so simple. I forgot to add `@JoinTable`

```
@JoinTable(name = "LAYER_USER", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(nullable = true))
```

Answer (score 2):

One important thing to be aware of is you shouldn't replace `this.members` with another list in `setMembers` unless you know you are doing it before you call `persist()`. Instead you need to clear `this.members` then add all the specified elements to it. The reason is that Hibernate can and will use its own proxied / instrumented collections classes when [de]serializing an entity, and you blow that away when overwriting the collection class. You should declare `members` as `final` and always initialize it to a non-null empty `List`.

See for example (3.6 but still relevant): http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-persistent, In particular:

> Notice how in Example 7.2, “Collection mapping using @OneToMany and
>   @JoinColumn” the instance variable parts was initialized with an
>   instance of HashSet. This is the best way to initialize collection
>   valued properties of newly instantiated (non-persistent) instances.
>   When you make the instance persistent, by calling persist(), Hibernate
>   will actually replace the HashSet with an instance of Hibernate's own
>   implementation of Set.

As long as you are messing with collection fields in this way, any number of strange things can happen.

---

Also, in general, you want to be careful about stating your invariants and such when accessing collections in this way, as it's easily possible to, e.g., create two `Layers` that reference the same collection internally, so that actions on one affect the other, or external actions on the passed-in collection affect the layer, e.g. the following code probably doesn't behave like you want it to:

```
List<MyUser> u = new ArrayList<MyUser>();
Layer a = new Layer();
Layer b = new Layer();

u.add(...);
a.setMembers(u);
b.setMembers(u);
u.clear();
```

Further, when you `persist()` one of the layers there, and Hibernate overwrites the field with its own collection class, the behavior then changes as the objects are no longer referencing the same collection:

```
// not only did u.clear() [possibly undesirably] affect a and b above, but:
session.persist(a);
u.add(...); // ... now it only affects b.
```

Comment: Okay, I'll fix that. You have a link to some official documentation for this?

Comment: Yes; I've updated with a documentation link. I linked to 3.6 but it will be in the same section for whatever version of Hibernate you are using. Also (updated) the exception is if you know you are setting the collection member *before* you call `persist()` on a new object.

Comment: Sorry, that's all I have.

Comment: By the way, yes your modification tests may change, but you haven't clearly stated your invariants when working with a `Layer`. See the bit I added to my answer above. Do you *really* want to be sharing internal collection instances between layers? If you do this your behavior *will* change after you persist and reload the objects (as they will no longer share references to the same collection). You should really rethink that.

Comment: No, I do not share internal collection instances between `Layers`. I currently am debugging the tests that now fail to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Okay, I figured out while my alternation tests were failing and could fix it. I also figured out it had something to do with the way I request the Entity, please see my edited question.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I figured it out (I forgot `@JoinTable`).